# A quickie about set theory notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm reading the first chapters of my discrete mathematics textbook and I couldn't help but wonder (perhaps I haven't seen enough examples) -- is it more appropriate to write that $a$ is an integer and within a set in the following way:
\begin{align}
a\in\left\{x\in\mathbb{Z}\big|\:b<a<c\right\},\tag{1}
\end{align}
or would it be better to break it up into two statements instead to have something like
\begin{align}
a\in\mathbb{Z},a\in\left(b,c\right)\tag{2}.
\end{align}
And I apologize in advance if some of you feel this is not a good question (perhaps too beginner-ish). I would just like to get all of the formalities down so that in the future I don't make a mistake.

Thanks,

Comment: I prefer (2) to (1). Another option is $a \in \mathbb{Z} \cap (b,c)$, which may be useful in some contexts but perhaps too formal in others. A further possibility is $[[ b + 1, c- 1]]$. That's not exactly right; it's supposed to be \llbracket and \rrbracket.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense actually. Great suggestion. +1

Comment: One could simply speak of "integral $a$ strictly between $b$ and $c$". There's nothing wrong with legible mathematics.

Comment: For nitpicking completeness: This question says $\;a\in\left\{x\in\mathbb{Z}\big|\:b<a<c\right\}\;$ but the intention is of course $\;a\in\left\{{\boxed a}\in\mathbb{Z}\big|\:b<a<c\right\}\;$ or $\;a\in\left\{x\in\mathbb{Z}\big|\:b<{\boxed x}<c\right\}\;$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're both fine. Don't get too hung up on notation, as long as your intent is clear.

My personal preference is to write something like: "let $a$ be an integer, where $b < a < c$." There's nothing wrong with mixing in statements in natural language.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose I just felt (2) a bit awkward because I had to reference the same variable twice in a row.

Comment: If you wanted to go in the spirit of the latter you could do $a \in \mathbb Z \cap (b,c)$. But as GFauxPas said, it's more important that you're clear.